# How do I add a local directory into github repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to add a whole directory into github. Below are the codes I am using to do that. the commit and push doesn't show anything new because I repeated the process to paste here; but those are commands I followed.

[image: code]

It adds the directory but I can not access  the files inside. It looks like below.

[image: github]

Is there any easier way to add the sub directory?
Is there any easier way to move repositories inside github?

Comment: Which directory do you want to add ? What's inside your Tutorials folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder image next to the `Machine-Learning-Tutorials` line in github suggests that you're adding a sub-module to an existing repository. That seems to be supported by the fact that you do a `git init`, but don't add a remote.

I'm guessing that `~/Documents/Merge/Git/Github/` is a git repository tracking github? If that's the case you don't need to do the `git init`--you already have a repository--and right now you'll actually want to remove the `~/Documents/Merge/Git/Github/Tutorials/.git` directory. At that point if you do a `git add Tutorials` it should add the actual files and let you push them up to github.

If you have a repository and you just want to add more files (in the current directory or a subdirectory) you just need to use `git add`, there's no need to `git init` a directory unless you want to track it as a separate repository (known as a submodule).